# Adding blocking users to a list

Tags: ios, twitter, sttwitter

Example: Twitter user A is blocked from Twitter user B.

If I use lists/members/create, it won't let me add user B to a list user A created. Correct.

If I use lists/members/create_all with user B in the list of users , it will let me add user B to a list created by user A. WRONG.

Is it supposed to be like that or is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

It's one of the many bugs with Tiwtter's list endpoints. (You still shouldn't get their Tweets when you get the list feed.)

Comment: I submitted an issue to Twitter in the meantime.